# Capital Punishment in the Ancient World

Tags: ancient-history, crime

Are there any examples of ancient cultures that did not practice capital punishment? (Prior to the fall of the Roman Empire ~500 AD)

Comment: I would say "no". Which is of course difficult to prove because there are so many cultures. The most common punishments is the ancient codes of law are fines and death penalty. (Prison terms are much later invention).

Comment: And mutilations.

Comment: @Alex an alternative to the death penalty was usually exile (although I do not know any culture that did not retain death penalty for the most serious offenses like treason or regicide)

Comment: @SJuan: yes, you are right, I forgot that Greeks also practiced exile, and the Romans to some extent. But I never heard of the prison terms.

Comment: The idea that punishment should be neither cruel nor unusual is a recent development. From what I've read, punishment in ancient societies tended to be both cruel and unusual.

Comment: It is easier (and cheaper) to exile or execute someone than to imprison him. maybe that is the reason why there is probably no culture with "crime" and without "capital punishment".

Comment: Here's why I dislike the wording of this question: If I say no, do you accept that? How do you know if I looked into every single world-wide civilization/culture? Moreover, how do I know?

Comment: It's an answerable question, an interesting one, and one not readily resolved with a quick trip to Wikipedia. What this stack exchange is about, really.